# How to run php when a POST response is received?

Tags: php, xml, api, post, response

I am collecting data on a form and sending the data via POST to an outside server that collects and distributes the form lead. The outside server sends an XML response back to my server.

I have set the Redirect URL for the response to my response php script. I want the script to parse the XML response and fire the pixel provided in one of the fields. I also would like the system to email me every time a response is received.

[How the system is layed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWLwS.jpg)

## My Problem

The system works if I manually enter an XML response and load it in my
browser. It does not execute the script when the response is sent in
the background.

Using `tshark` I have been monitoring traffic and everytime the form is submitted, php script is hit, but nothing executes.

## My Current Code

```
<?php

//Example Post from Lead Server
$server_output2=
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <status>Unmatched</status>
  <lead_id>69</lead_id>
  <tracking_pixel>https://demo.leadportal.com/genericPostlead.php?TYPE=79&amp;amp;SRC=pixeltestingforcege</tracking_pixel>
</response>'; 

//Live Server Response 
$server_output = file_get_contents('php://input');
if (!empty($server_output)) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($server_output) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
}

//XML Parse of Lead Server Response
$status=$xml->status;
$lead_id=$xml->lead_id;
$pixel=$xml->tracking_pixel;

?>

<!-- This is the HTML Section to test and Display the Status and LeadID -->
The status is <span style="font-weight:bold;color:red;"><?php if(!empty($status)) echo $status; else{echo "n/a";} ?></span> and the lead id is <span style="font-weight:bold;color:red;"><?php if(!empty($lead_id)) echo $lead_id; else{echo "n/a";} ?></span>

<br>
<!-- This is the Pixel Fire from the Response-->
<h3>Pixel Here!
<iframe src="<?php echo $pixel; ?>" height="1" width="1" frameborder="1" style="border:medium double red"></iframe></h3>

<?php
$to = "email@gmail.com";
$subject = "XML Response";
$message =" 
Hello
$xml
$server_output
$server_output2

";

$headers = 'From: webmaster@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: no-reply@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: A redirect is always a `GET` request from the browser, it can't send `POST` data from the outside server.

Answer (score 0):

## Problems

I ended up having a large number of limitations in this project due to the 3rd party server and our use of wordpress with ninja forms.

Basically the 3rd party service could not send their response to a specific location. it just returned a post response to where the original data post was sent.

Ninja forms did not have a way to capture responses unless in debug mode. When in debug mode it created an array which had to be parsed

## Solution

I created a plugin to tap into the Ninja Forms Web Hooks Plugin and pulled the response from there.

I then parsed the XML response to Log and grab necessary values including the pixel URL.

Finallly I used cURL to fire the pixel

## The Code

```
<?php
public function fire_pixel ( $response ) {
            
        
        $filename = './webhook.log';
        $xml_array = $response['body'];
                
        
        if (!empty($xml_array)) {
            $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_array) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
        
                $xml_status = $xml->status;
                $lead_id = $xml->lead_id;
                $pixel = $xml->tracking_pixel;
                $xml_error = $xml->error;
            
                    if ($xml_error  == ''){
                        $xml_error = "No Error";
                    }
                    if ($lead_id  == ''){
                        $lead_id = "Error";
                    }
                    if ($pixel  == ''){
                        $pixel_message = "No Tracking Pixel";
                    }
                    else {
                        $pixel_message = '';
                    }
                    
            $log  = "Date: ".date("F j, Y, g:i a").PHP_EOL.
                    "Status: ".$xml_status.PHP_EOL.
                    "Lead ID: ".$lead_id.PHP_EOL.
                    "Pixel: ".$pixel.$pixel_message.PHP_EOL.
                    "Error: ".$xml_error.PHP_EOL.
                    "-------------------------".PHP_EOL;
            file_put_contents($filename, $log, FILE_APPEND);
            
            if (!empty($pixel)) {
                $pixel_results = file_get_contents($pixel); 

        $date = date(DATE_RFC2822);
        $current = file_get_contents($filename);
        $current .= $date;
        $current .= $pixel_results;
        $current .= " : cURL   :  cURL STARTED  | cURL started\n";
        file_put_contents($filename, $current);
        
        
            $ch = curl_init();

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $pixel);
                curl_exec($ch);

            $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);


        $current = file_get_contents($filename);
        $current .= $date . " : cURL   :  cURL STATUS   | " . $http_code . "\n";
        file_put_contents($filename, $current);

        curl_close($ch);
        }
    } 
}
    ?>
```